# virtualhost in tomcat 7 only takes defaulthost

Tags: tomcat, cpanel, virtualhost, server.xml

I have two domains, and only takes **defaultHost**.

I introduce **domain2.com**, and shows me the application of `domain1.mx`

I use ngasi application with **tomcat 7** and **Cpanel**.
With **filezilla** i access to file `server.xml` in conf folder of tomcat.

In each folder (**vdtDoc_app** and **vdt_app**), i have an `ROOT.war` file (each **.war** file contains differents projects)

I have this configuration in the file `server.xml` in **tomcat 7**:

```
<Connector port="12205" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="12206" address="0.0.0.0" 
               useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
               />

    <Connector port="12206" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="0.0.0.0" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="./conf/keystore" keystorePass="coolgeek" />

 <Connector port="12207" address="0.0.0.0" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="12206" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="domain1.mx">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

       <Host name="domain1.mx"  appBase="/home/user/public_html/vdtDoc_app"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
            <Alias>www.domain1.mx</Alias> 
       </Host>

        <Host name="domain2.com"  appBase="/home/user/public_html/vdt_app"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
            <Alias>www.domain2.com</Alias> 
        </Host>

    </Engine>
```

I must have some configuration in **Cpanel** and/or **Ngasi**?
or I need to configure more things in the `server.xml` file?

Answer (score 0):

I've learnt the hard way that its just better off having a server with default httpd, tomcat installed.

I've attempted it with cPanel(multiple times) but it just does not like cPanel.